# Debugging sub-queries in TSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, debugging, visual-studio-2005

How do I debug a complex query with multiple nested sub-queries in SQL Server 2005?

I'm debugging a stored procedure and trigger in Visual Studio 2005.  I'd like to be able to see what the results of these sub-queries are, as I feel that this is where the bug is coming from.  An example query (slightly redacted) is below:

```
UPDATE
               foo
          SET
               DateUpdated = ( SELECT TOP 1 inserted.DateUpdated FROM inserted )
              ...
          FROM
               tblEP ep
               JOIN tblED ed ON ep.EnrollmentID = ed.EnrollmentID
          WHERE
               ProgramPhaseID = ( SELECT ...)
```

Visual Studio doesn't seem to offer a way for me to Watch the result of the sub query.  Also, if I use a temporary table to store the results (temporary tables are used elsewhere also) I can't view the values stored in that table.

Is there anyway that I can add a watch or in some other way view these sub-queries?  I would love it if there was some way to "Step Into" the query itself, but I imagine that wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Ok first I would be leary  of using subqueries in a trigger. Triggers should be as fast as possible, so get rid of any correlated subqueries which might run row by row instead of in a set-based fashion. Rewrite to joins.  If you only want to update records based on what was in the inserted table, then join to it. Also join to the table you are updating. Exactly what are you trying to accomplish with this trigger? It might be easier to give advice if we understood the business rule you are trying to implement.

To debug a trigger this is what I do.

I write a script to:

1. Do the actual insert to the table
   without the trigger on on it
2. Create a temp table named #inserted
   (and/or one named #deleted)
3. Populate the table as I would expect
   the inserted table in the trigger to
   be populated from the insert you do.
4. Add the trigger code (minus the
   create or alter trigger parts)
   substituting #inserted every time I
   reference inserted. (if you plan to
   run multiple times until you are
   ready to use it in a trigger throw
   it in an explicit transaction and
   rollback after checking your
   results.
5. Add a query to check the table(s)
   you are changing with the trigger for
   the values you wanted to change.
6. Now if you need to add debug
   statements to see what is happening
   between steps, you can do so.
7. Run making changes until you get the
   results you want.
8. Once you have the query working as
   you expect it to, it is easy to take
   the # signs off inserted and use it
   to create the body of the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually do in this type of scenerio:
Print out the exact sqls getting generated by each subquery
Then run each of then in the Management Studio as suggested above.
You should check if different parts are giving you the right data you expect.